# Spam flag is adding a second downvote

Tags: support, flags, downvotes, spam

I downvoted and then flagged the following two posts as spam (10k only):

[Unsure about word embeddings, POS re: using a Neural Net for NLP classification.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856296/unsure-about-word-embeddings-pos-re-using-a-neural-net-for-nlp-classification/44333521#44333521)

[NLP: Qualitatively "positive" vs "negative" sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122595/nlp-qualitatively-positive-vs-negative-sentence/44333602#44333602)

Afterwards I noticed that in both cases I had downvoted the answer **twice**, one from the **actual downvote** and another from the **spam flag**. Is this intended functionality, or was it a coincidence and someone else had also downvoted at the same time?

Comment: I would downvote it three times if they'd let me...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

When a post gets flagged as spam, the community user also adds a downvote to the post.

This is what you have been seeing.

If this spam flag get invalidated, the downvote is removed.

Comment: When does this downvote get applied, clearly it is *before* the post actually gets deleted as otherwise I wouldn't see it (I don't have the rep)

Comment: It is all done server side and the real-time system will then update the page - there's a race there, sometimes the delete message comes in first, sometimes the downvote message comes first...

Comment: Whenever I flag I see a downvote appear. You'll notice this when you do it often. I think the same occurs if it's flagged as rude/abusive.

Comment: wonder why this wasn't tagged as status by design. Also if memory serves community vote can be retracted later in case if spam / rude flag is deemed invalid

Comment: @gnat - we don't normally tag things that are not bug reports with status tags.

Comment: I see, that makes sense

Comment: If the flag was marked helpful, and the post corrected (with affiliation, for example), will the vote age away?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't think it goes away. The downvote was made by the system, and the system can't be sure if the post improved, so no.